# Python communicate into VM windows app

Tags: python, virtual-machine, ipc, virtualization

How can I setup a virtualized Ubuntu on real Windows so I can have two apps communicating simple messages between them? VM can be offline, no internet access. Real system probably offline too.

Comment: Presumably one app is running on Ubuntu and another on Windows?  The simplest is to have a shared mount point/directory.  Most VM systems will support that, although the details vary between products.  You could then use a named pipe (see `mkfifo`) created on Ubuntu.  Both apps read/write to the named pipe as if it was a file.  This avoids the comms issues.  You still need to carefully work out the design before hand to avoid synchronisation issues.

Comment: Get something like VMWare or VirtualBox or even Hyperv if you have a 64-bit machine, install Ubuntu on it and then run it - you probably need to use HostOnly comms if you are communicating through udp/tcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host<->VM communication on Windows host can be implemented in several ways, independently of hypervisor you are using:

- Host Only network - just assign static IP for host and machine, and use sockets api to transfer your data via virtual network. Very good for large amount of data, but require a little bit time for configuration.
- Virtual COM ports - if you don't want to use sockets api and want to write data to files(on linux VM)/named pipes(on windows host). This can be simpler because require almost zero configuration, but it will not work very well with large amount of data.

Choose what will fit your needs.